# Can we find the _local_ class-name of an object instantiated from a class imported with 'import as'?

Tags: python, python-import

If I import a class and rename it by subclassing, it's fairly simple to find the new class name:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> class Test(Timer):
...     pass
... 
>>> test = Test()
>>> test.__class__.__name__
'Test'
```

However, if I alias the class as I import it, it retains the name from its host module:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer as Test2
>>> test2 = Test2()
>>> test2.__class__.__name__
'Timer'
```

Later, I want to provide user-facing output which is aware of the name they've given the class in their namespace. Consider:

```
def report_stats(timer):
    print("Runtime statistics for %s:" % timer.__class__.__name__)
    ...
```

Is there a way to get a string reading "Test2", short of iterating over variables in the namespace to test for an exact match?

Comment: No. You'd have to look it up, and it could always have multiple names. The name it was at definition time is all that's saved on the class. When you subclass it, you're not renaming it, you're creating a new class with the original class as one of its bases.

Comment: If you'll answer this, @agf, I will accept it. I'll also be providing my own answer based on the terrible things I found at the bottom of the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really terrible answer to my own question; I won't be accepting this since it's probably pretty fragile (I only tested for a limited set of call circumstances). I mostly just hunted this down for the challenge; I will most likely be using something more durable for my actual use case.

This assumes we have access to the **init** function of the class we're trying to import as blah, and some sort of persistent external data store, at least for more complicated edge cases:

```
import inspect, dis

class Idiom(object):
    description = None
    alias = None

    def __init__(self, desc):
        global data_ob
        self.description = desc

        if self.__class__.__name__ == 'Idiom':
            #cheat like hell to figure out who called us
            self.alias = data_ob.name_idiom(inspect.currentframe().f_back)
        else:
            self.alias = self.__class__.__name__

class DataOb(object):
    code = None
    locations = {}
    LOAD_NAME = 101
    codelen = None

    def name_idiom(self, frame):
        if not self.code:
            self.code = frame.f_code
            self.codelen = len(self.code.co_code)
            self.locations = {y:x for x, y in dis.findlinestarts(self.code)}

        target_line = frame.f_lineno
        addr_index = self.locations[target_line]+1
        name_index = self.code.co_code[addr_index]

        # there's a chance we'll get called again this line,
        # so we want to seek to the next LOAD_NAME instance(101)
        addr_index += 1
        while addr_index < self.codelen:
            if self.code.co_code[addr_index] == self.LOAD_NAME:
                self.locations[target_line] = addr_index
                break
            addr_index += 1

        return self.code.co_names[name_index]
```

The short explanation of how this works is:

- we look up the previous frame from the init function
- obtain the code object
- find bytecode locations for the start of every line in the code
- use the line-number from the frame to grab the bytecode location for the start of that line
- locate a LOAD_NAME indicator in the bytecode for this line (I don't really follow this; my code assumes it'll be there)
- look in the next bytecode position for an index which indicates which position in the code.co_names tuple contains the "name" of the LOAD_NAME call

From here we can do something like:

```
>>> from rabbit_hole import Idiom as timer_bob
>>> with timer_bob("down the rabbit hole"):
...     waste_some_time = list(range(50000))
... 
timer_bob: down the rabbit hole
    runtime: 0:00:00.001909, children: 0:00:00, overhead: 0:00:00.001909
```

Comment: Congratulations, you win this week's Evil Python Award.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I hope I hope I hope it comes with high perpetual maintenance costs.